# Better solution for animating width

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have a block over a text and i want to reveal the text and make the width of the block zero
I'm using gsap but as far as i know it is bad for performance to animate width,
and since i'm gonna use this animation quite a lot i'm worried to animate width

so is there is a better solution for my little problem ?

```js
gsap.to('.block', {
  duration: 1, width: 0, ease: Power4.easeIn}, 0.2);
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}
.block {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  hello world
  <span class="block"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: [Same post on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24083-animating-width/). Short answer: use scaleX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider an animation using transform and have better performance

```js
gsap.to('.block', {
  duration: 1, transform: 'translateX(-100%)', ease: Power4.easeIn}, 0.2);
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.block {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  hello world
  <span class="block"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Or use scaleX instead.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a solution in animation properties of CSS. Using CSS instead of
JavaScript (JS) will delegate computing the animated values to the browser's layout engine instead of re-implementing them in your code.

At a high level your animation will be a `from`, `to` state where the `from` is full
width and `to` is 0 width. You express this with a [`@keyframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) rule where you can animate **ANY** CSS property. This way you can combine `@keyframes` on different properties.

These are some good introductory notes about animations in CSS [css-animation-101](https://github.com/cssanimation/css-animation-101), [using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animation/Using_CSS_animations)

For you particular use case something like this should do

```
@keyframes unveil {
   from {
       width: 100%;
   }
   to {
       width: 0%;
   }
}

.block {
    animation-name: unveil;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

Then you can either add the `block` class to the span directly in the HTML or use some JavaScript to toggle/add the class in response to an event.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, how ever what i meant by better solution i meant alternatives to the width, or it is fine to animate width in this case ? thank you again for your code much better and easier

Comment: "Using CSS instead of JavaScript (JS) will delegate it to the browser instead of your code." This is incorrect. In both cases it is delegating things to the browser and is based on your code. Whether or not you use CSS or JS to animate has no effect on that. Using CSS animations is *much* harder to have full control over how and when animations fire.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of to increase the performance while still using Gsap is to lower the duration of the width transition of the block, as well as lower the fps of the animation by adding ***gsap.ticker.fps('framerate')*** to the javascript.
the default framerate is 60 fps, so try changing it to anything lower than that. Though I'm not entirely sure if that would make a huge improvement.

```js
gsap.ticker.fps(24); 
  //caps framerate at 24
gsap.to('.block', {duration: 0.5, width: 0, ease: Power4.easeIn}, 0.2);
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
  .block {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js">
</script>
<h1>
  hello world
  <span class="block"></span>
</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your suggestion will give a try, i have another question if you don't mind is it possible to do ease: Power4.easeIn transition with pure css ?

Comment: @Konya I think it's similar to the one here, 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_cubic-bezier.asp though you have to input the values manually to produce the same effect.

Comment: you can learn more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function

Answer (score -1):

You can use css animations:

```js
function toggleAnimation() {
    $('.block').toggleClass("animated");
}
```

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}
.block {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes custom-animation {
   from {
       width: 100%;
   }
   to {
       width: 0%;
   }
}

.block.animated {
    animation: custom-animation 1s ease-in 0.5s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  hello world
  <span class="block"></span>
  
  
</h1>

<button onclick="toggleAnimation();">Toggle animation</button>
```

In my sample, the block needs the `animated` class to actually animates. For the demo, I used a button to add this class.

Comment: Thank you so much guyz for your answer, but what about the stagger effect ? i mean in gsap is so easy is it possible with the suggested solutions ?